# error in googlemaps in python

Tags: python, google-maps

I have the python google maps for python. i have this code:

```
from googlemaps import GoogleMaps
place1 = raw_input("your address: ")
place = raw_input("Destination: ")
gmaps = GoogleMaps(api_key)
directions = gmaps.direction(place1, place)
for step in directions['Directions']['Routes']['seconds'][0]['Steps']:
     print step['descriptionHtml']
```

and i get this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\test.py", line 152, in <module>
    directions = gmaps.direction(place1, place)
AttributeError: 'GoogleMaps' object has no attribute 'direction'
```

i'm trying to ask the user for their address and the Destination and then find the directions.

Comment: What about the error message don't you understand?

Comment: you haven't defined your api_key, ie. api_key = "<api key goes here>"

Comment: I took this code from the website and i get an error so how do i identify the api_key?

Comment: i tried api_key = (my key) and it does nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the method is actually `GoogleMaps.directions(origin, destination, **kwargs)`, notice the "s" on the method name.  Here's a [link](http://py-googlemaps.sourceforge.net/#directions) to the API docs.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have a Google Maps API key. You need to sign up for one here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

By the way, when you say "the python google maps for python," what are you referring to exactly? Is it [this project](http://code.google.com/p/pymaps/%E2%80%8E)?

Comment: i used this website http://py-googlemaps.sourceforge.net/ I signed up for a key and put api_key = (my key) and it still did not work.

Comment: Can you edit your code above to show us how you set the variable api_key? In the code example, you have not set it, i.e. there is no api_key = 'aRIFUWGOIEW298275r0' or whatever. Also, are you getting a different error now, or the same one?

Comment: i dont get the same error i get this one: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\test.py", line 152, in <module>
    directions = gmaps.direction(place1, place)
AttributeError: 'GoogleMaps' object has no attribute 'direction'